# javascript module pattern - don't understand the return values

Tags: javascript

I was trying to understand some code I found:

```
var myApplication = function(){
 var name = 'Chris';
 var age = '34';
 var status = 'single';
 function createMember(){
 // [...]
 }
 function getMemberDetails(){
 // [...]
 }
 return{
 create:createMember,
 get:getMemberDetails
 }
}();
//myApplication.get() and myApplication.create() now work.
```

I don't understand the syntax of the return and why it works. The explanation I found had to do with pointers, but I really don't understand what it was talking about. Can someone explain this to me?

Comment: it's not the syntax of 'the return', it's the syntax of an object literal that you need to understand.

Comment: There are no pointers in JavaScript. What tutorial did you find this at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`myApplication` receives the return of the execution of the function. This return is an object.

That object has two properties: `create` and `get`.

The value of the `create` (as well as the value of `get`) property is a function, defined earlier in the **local scope** of `myApplication`.

When you call `myApplication.get()` you are executing the function.

Answer (score 2):

This statement returns the functions of the scope in the function myApplication

```
return {
    create:createMember,
    get:getMemberDetails
}
```

It works because you expose the references `createMember` and `getMemberDetails` through an object.

**EDIT**

Also, myApplication is the result of the function called, it is immediately called, at declaration thanks to the following syntax

```
(function myFunction() {
    // some code
}())
```